# How to search for the types of many functions in one go

Tags: haskell, ghci

How can I search for the types of `length, take, drop, splitAt, !!` and `replicate` all in one go, without entering in `:t length`, `:t take`, `:t drop`, etc, for all of these functions?

Answer (score 12):

ghci includes a `:def` command. The command has the form `:def <name> <function>`, where `<name>` is the new command to define, and `<function>` is a Haskell function of type `String -> IO String` saying how to convert arguments to the new command into an existing chain of commands. We can use this to our advantage: we'll make a new command, `:manyt`, which takes a list of names and runs `:t` on each. For simplicity, I'll split on spaces; but if you want to ask for the types of many *expressions* rather than just names you may want to do some more complicated delimiting/parsing. So, in `~/.ghci`, add a line like this:

```
:def manyt (\s -> Prelude.return (Prelude.unlines [":t " Prelude.++ n | n <- Prelude.words s]))
```

(The excessive `Prelude` qualification is so that this works even when `-XNoImplicitPrelude` is enabled.) Try it out:

```
> :manyt length take drop splitAt (!!) replicate
length :: Foldable t => t a -> Int
take :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
drop :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
splitAt :: Int -> [a] -> ([a], [a])
(!!) :: [a] -> Int -> a
replicate :: Int -> a -> [a]
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it too simple to suggest searching the type of a tuple or these functions?

```
Prelude> :t (length, take, drop, splitAt)
(length, take, drop, splitAt)
  :: Foldable t =>
     (t a1 -> Int, Int -> [a2] -> [a2], Int -> [a3] -> [a3],
      Int -> [a4] -> ([a4], [a4]))
Prelude>
```